# Inequality of Matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality

Consider $A$, $B$  be two symmetric positive definite matrices and $A^{-1}<B^{-1}$, i.e; $(A^{-1}-B^{-1})$ is a negative definite matrix. Then can we conclude that $A>B$?  Or at least under what conditions $A>B$ will be true. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since you have $A^{-1}<B^{-1}$, conjugating with $A^{1/2}$ you get
$$
I<A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{-1/2}.
$$
But $A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{-1/2}=(A^{1/2}B^{-1/2})(A^{1/2}B^{-1/2})^*$. Since $XX^*$ and $X^*X$ are both positive definite and have the same spectrum (for invertible $X$), we get
$$
I<(A^{1/2}B^{-1/2})^*A^{1/2}B^{-1/2}=B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}.
$$
Conjugating with $B^{1/2}$ we get $B<A$.

Comment: You are welcome!